# Challenging CSS Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

I'm stumped with the implementation on this one.

The yellow square/bg appears on hover and there should be an offset like that one in the image below. Im using bootstrap by the way. Any help or a point in the right direction would be highly appreciated. Thanks

[This image is the design mockup and what i am trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9v6j.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please include your code in the question. It's impossible for us to guess why this is not working as you want it to.

Comment: Hi @DarrenSweeney thanks! The image is the design mockup and what i am trying to achieve. I just couldn't think of a way to implement that kind of hover behavior.

Comment: It's expected that you at least research and try. Then if you have issues, come back with them and people will happily help if they can. Also, I'd ask your designer if the yellow box MUST be behind the blue lines, you could be in for a world of pain trying to implement that and keep it responsive and looking good on all devices.

Comment: Consider using :after selector of the hovered element. On this pseudo-element, you'll be able to use a background color, and an offset with transform css property. Give it a try, and come back if you are still stuck with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very rudimentary example, but should give you an idea. Using a before pseudo element, positioned absolutely with a z-index of -1 and containers with a transparent background should give you the desired results. See the example.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #dfdbe5;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='40' height='40' viewBox='0 0 40 40'%3E%3Cg fill-rule='evenodd'%3E%3Cg fill='%239C92AC' fill-opacity='0.4'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 38.59l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L1.41 40H0v-1.41zM0 1.4l2.83 2.83 1.41-1.41L1.41 0H0v1.41zM38.59 40l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L40 38.59V40h-1.41zM40 1.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L38.59 0H40v1.41zM20 18.6l2.83-2.83 1.41 1.41L21.41 20l2.83 2.83-1.41 1.41L20 21.41l-2.83 2.83-1.41-1.41L18.59 20l-2.83-2.83 1.41-1.41L20 18.59z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.row1,
.row2 {
  width: calc(100vw - 64px);
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  clear: both;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.row1::after,
.row2::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.row1 {
  z-index: 1;
}
.row2 {
  clear: left;
  z-index: 0;
}

span[class^="container"] {
  width: calc(100% - 64px / 3);
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid #6690ce;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

span[class^="container"]:hover::before {
  content: "";
  background: #ffd100;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 3px;
  left: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="row1">
    <span class="container1">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </span>
    <span class="container2">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</span>
    <span class="container3">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </span>
    <span class="container4">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </span>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <span class="container5">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </span>
    <span class="container6">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. </span>
    <span class="container7">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: holy! I think this is it! I think i can manage with this, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. I've edited it to include the lower overlay, which I missed on the first pass.

Comment: I implemented this already on my code, the only problem i have now is that orange bg gets buried if you set a background on the parent div because of the z-index: -1, any chance for a workaround?

Comment: I've updated the example to include backgrounds on both a body wrapper and row wrappers and it seems to be working fine. Do you mean adding a background to the "container1" or "container2"?

Comment: This is a weird issue, its supposed to work like with your example, I uploaded a video, please take a look: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqTGHld7zkI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: You're missing z-index on your row container. You'll see in my example I have `z-index:1` on row 1, and `z-index:0` on row 2. Without that the pseudo element disappears behind the background.

Comment: For a more accurate solution, I put my code on codepen. I also already put in the z-index: 1 on row. Still nada. Here: https://codepen.io/dan-allen-pantinople/pen/gjEEzp

If you remove the background: gray, the hover effect works.

Comment: Your row needs a `position:relative;`. Check my example again, I updated it earlier to mimic your layout.

Comment: That did it! Awesome! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

This example will give you an ability to do an animated hover. It uses a css transform:

```css
.row {
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.col-content::before {
  transition: all 0.25s ease-in;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  z-index: -1;
}

.col:hover .col-content::before {
  background: orange;
  transform: translateX(5px) translateY(5px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- 
   Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
   -->
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <div class="col-content">
            1 of 2
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <div class="col-content">
            2 of 2
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
         <div class="col-content">
            1 of 3
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <div class="col-content">
            2 of 3
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <div class="col-content">
            3 of 3
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me the idea to animate it this way! So neat!

Answer (score 0):

This is one approach to implement a hover effect with offset:

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9kh5fq1s/8/)

If you are able to provide a code example, I can help you a bit more.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="heading">
  <h1>Hey</h1>
 </div>
</div>

.container{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

.heading:hover {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative; 
  margin: 4px 0;
  left: 5px;
}
```